# Another jquery and IE issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

As you can see on my webpage http://klaunfizia.pl/damian/ jQuery seems to be totally ignored by Internet Explorer. You can see it on Portfolio section where description and images are being loaded on different browsers and not on IE. I checked the developer console and here's what I got:

```
SCRIPT1002: Syntax error
File: jquery.js, Line: 7993, Column: 6
```

Syntax error in jQuery file I've downloaded from official website? Is this error preventing my jquery scripts from being loaded?

Here's the link to my external scripts file:

http://klaunfizia.pl/damian/scripts.js

Comment: i rather believe your scripts file is causing the error. try leaving it out and reload the site, jquery should load. also, beware that jquery dropped support for old ie browsers

Comment: Be aware that jquery 2.0 is not compatible with IE 8 and below

Comment: Actually, looking at the loaded resources, jQuery is loaded four times from different places as far as I can see ?

Answer (score 0):

You load 2 versions of jQuery (one via swiat_edgePreload.js, and the other with a regular script tag), maybe causing problems on IE ?

Comment: I don't think that loading jQuery through swiat_edgePreload.js affects the entire page, because removing jQuery load from index.htm makes the whole menu disappear. That's strange, because it seems that jQuery is actually working, but scripts from external pages not.

Comment: Well, swiat_edgePreload loads asynchronously jQuery, so $ object is probably not available when you're calling jQuery methods. Anyway, it's  totally useless to load several times jQuery. Oh, and all your jQuery code should be wrapped in a single script tag (while it's not, at the end of your index)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see on my webpage http://klaunfizia.pl/damian/ ... url not working

Comment: That's odd why for some people url doesn't work. It works fine for most. Maybe try http://klaunfizia.pl/damian/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problemy by moving all the scripts from external file to html file. I don't know why IE has problems with it, but this is the solution [facepalm]